# Reload record detail lightning page on edit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Is there a way to reload the Lightning page after saving the record detail? I have embedded a custom Lightning component on the Lightning page and trying to reload the page to use the updated field values on the record.

Comment: Are you updating the field values from Your custom Lightning Component? And you expect the standard detail page to be updated based on update from custom component?

Comment: @sanketkumar Its the other way around. The custom component has a form that has fields from different objects and few fields with values prepopulated from the record detail. When the value of a field is updated on the record detail, it is not reflecting in the form unless I force reload the page. If it were the component that reloads the page, I can use force:refreshView. But since this is the other way around I am not sure how to refresh the page (or reload all components on the page) on record save.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code, if success is returned below code line should be fired.
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();

A sample method can be written as

```
refresh : function(component, event, helper) {
var action = component.get('c.myController');
action.setCallback(component,
    function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        } else {
             //do something
        }
    }
);
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

}
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation

Are you in the context of a custom lightning app? The default refreshView event is only available within the Lightning Experience / mobile Salesforce-App context. Say if you want to use the event within a .app you have to register and handle the event manually and cannot use the out-of-the-box behaviour.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one.htm

Comment: Tried this but the force:refreshView event does not reload the whole page, and my component does not get the updated field values from the record detail.

Comment: You getting success as state from apex?
Try using Location.reload(); to refresh the full view

Answer (score 0):

`force:refreshView` is used to refresh the view when you need to get new data. Something like this:

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```